# Converting Map<Enum, Object> to JSON

Tags: java, json, dictionary, gson

I build a json on server like that:

```
List<Object> resp = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : buffer.toString().split("\\n")) {
    for (String data : str.split("\\s")) {
        if (data.matches("[\\w|\\W]+") && !data.isEmpty()) {
            Child.set(Child.children, "null");
            Child.set(Child.parent, chain.name());
            Child.set(Child.name, data);
        }
        Child.setChild(Child.get());
    }
}

Child.set(Child.children, Child.getChild().toArray());
Child.set(Child.parent, "null");
Child.set(Child.name, chain.name());
```

The problem is that Child is `HashMap<Child, Object>` but when I put `Child.set(Child.children, Child.getChild().toArray());` to Map and then convert the Map object with Google Gson to Json it breaks with error:

```
oejw.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455:java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

The problem is not with WebSocket I think, because when I'm previous convert to json the `Child.getChild().toArray()` and then put it to the map, there are no any errors, but the generated json is not fully corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with converting to Json. Gson converts with stack overflow error.
Solves with using JSONObject and JSONArray.